# Concrete Filtration at specific time

Tags: measure-theory, filtrations

Consider random variables $X(t) \geq 0$ for $t=0,1,2,3$ defined on a filtered  probability space with $\Omega=\{u,d\}^3$, where $u>d$ and $u,d \geq 0$.

I holds  $$X(t)(\omega)=w_t$$ for any $\omega=(\omega_1,.., \omega_3)$

The filtration at $t$ is generated by $X(t)$, meaning : $\mathcal{F}(t)=\sigma(X(1),..,X(t))$

For $t=0$ define $\mathcal{F}(0)=\{ \emptyset, \Omega\}$.

I want to compute $\mathcal{F}(1),\mathcal{F}(2)$.

Since I know at $t=1$, which state $X(1)$ has taken, I would conclude: $$\mathcal{F}(1)=\{ (u,u,u), (u,d,d), (u,u,d), (u,d,u)\}$$
I assumed $X(1)=u$.
In similar way I would argue for $t=2$:$$ \mathcal{F}(2)=\{ (u,u,d), (u,u,d)\}$$
assuming $X(1)=X(2)=u$.

What do you think?

Comment: A filtration is a set of sets, while you have written $\mathcal F(1)$ and $\mathcal F(2)$ as subsets of $\Omega$. I think you will require a very detailed answer probably with the definition of filtration and calculating filtrations, is that right? Are you seeing filtrations etc. for the first time in this course you are studying / work you are doing?

Comment: @TeresaLisbon: Sorry for the late answer. I did not see it. This is my first time dealing with filtrations. It would be if you can give an answer of calculating such filtrations to get a feeling for them. It would help me a lot:)

Comment: I apologize for not answering immediately.

Comment: No problem! All I expected from you was a confirmation. Your question otherwise was absolutely fine! I will write a nice answer for you.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon: Thank you very much:) I very much appreciate your help:)

Comment: Welcome Alif. I will get cracking soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### The meaning of a filtration

See, the idea of a filtration is of storing *accumulated information*.

What does this mean? Well, imagine you are travelling on a bus, on a route you've never been on. You note down the stops that come your way : when you are at a certain time, you know everything about a the place you are at and everything before it, but you don't quite know what comes afterwards. That's the point of a filtration : to store the list of events that you know have happened within a certain time, or are decided by a certain list of random variables, you use a filtration.

For example  by time $1$ you are expected to have seen $X_1$, and therefore $\mathcal F(1)$ is the list of events that you know for sure have occurred or not, by *only looking at $X_1$*.

Note that an event is a subset of the sample space i.e. $\Omega$. So $\mathcal F(1)$ is a subset of $\mathcal P(\Omega)$, the set of subsets of $\Omega$. Every element of $\mathcal F(1)$ is a subset of $\Omega$. You seem to have written just one event when you wrote down $\mathcal F(1)$ ; that event turns out to be a good example though.

One can similarly speak of $\mathcal F(2)$.

Key point : The occurence of an event in $\mathcal F(1)$ depends $\color{green}{\text{only on } X_1}$, and every such event will belong to $\mathcal F(1)$.

Why do you think that $\mathcal F(0) = \{\emptyset , \Omega\}$? This is because these are the two events you can be *certain* have occured or not without knowing *anything* : for any other event, you will have to know *something* about the process to know if it occurred or not.

##### Examples

We will take examples, and in the process point out a stunning commonality of the affirmative cases, with the help of which I will mention a general pattern that one can use to form the filtrations in the blink of an eye.

Let's take the event $E_1 = \{(u,u,d)\}$. Is this event in $\mathcal F(1)$? Can I decide using *just* $X_1$ if $E_1$ has occurred or not? The answer is *no*, because if $X_1 = u$ occurs, I'd still have to check if $X_2 = u$ and $X_3 = d$ happen, only then can $E$ happen. So I need to go beyond $X_1$ to check if $E_1$ occurs or not.

Let's take $E_2 = \{(u,u,d),(u,d,u),(d,d,u)\}$. Is this event in $\mathcal F(1)$? Once again, the answer is no : for example, if $X_1 = u$ then I can't conclude that $E_2$ has occurred : what if $X_2= X_3 = d$ happens? Then $E_2$ won't happen. So $E_2$ very much depends upon $X_2,X_3$.

Let's take $E_3 = \{(u,u,d),(u,d,u),(u,d,d),(u,u,u)\}$. Is this event in $\mathcal F(1)$? The answer is *YES*. Here's why : if $X_1 = u$ then *regardless of what $X_2$ and $X_3$ are*, the event $E_3$ occurs. On the other hand, if $X_1 = d$ then once again the event certainly does not occur. In conclusion, $E_3$ depends only on $X_1$.

Let's take $E_4 = \{(u,u,d),(u,d,u),(u,d,d),(u,u,u) , (d,u,u)\}$. Is this event in $\mathcal F(1)$? The answer is NO, because if $X_1 = d$ then it is still possible that $X_2 = d$ so then $E_4$ won't occur.

Now we are beginning to see things : what's happened in $E_3$ is that after $X_1 = u$, *all possible combinations of $X_2$,$X_3$ were covered in $E_3$*. Because of that , the event $E_3$ said : I don't care about $X_2$ or $X_3$, just tell me if $X_1 = u$ or not. The other events did not . $E_4$ said :  if $X_1 = u$ then I occur, but if $X_1 =d$ then you'll need to check $X_2$ and $X_3$  to see if I occur or not.

This idea of covering all possible future combinations is the key to forming sets that belong to filtrations. Including all possible combinations says "I don't care about those coordinates" and that's what you want, isn't it?

##### Observing the pattern

The pattern is thus noticed as follows : if you want an event to depend only on a certain bunch of random variables, make sure that the event includes *all possible combinations* of the rest of the variables.

Now, what does that mean in the context of $\mathcal F(1) = \sigma(X_1)$? Well, you need all possible combinations of $X_2,X_3$ in any event in $\mathcal F(1)$.

Of course both the empty set and $\Omega$ belong to $\mathcal F(1)$. There are *only two* other possible events in $\mathcal F(1)$. Why? Well, let's imagine an event $E \in \mathcal F(1)$. If it contains $(u,*,*)$ for any value of $*$ then it must contain *all possible combinations* so that the value of those $*$s don't matter for $E$. In particular, it must contain $E_3 = \{(u,u,d),(u,d,u),(u,u,u),(u,d,d)\}$.

Similarly, if $E$ contains $\{(d,*,*)\}$ for any value of $*$ then it must contain all possible combinations ,so it must contain $\{(d,u,u),(d,u,d),(d,d,u),(d,d,d)\}$.

That gives us only these sets, which form $\mathcal F(1)$ :
$$
\mathcal F(1) =\Big\{\emptyset , \Omega , \{(u,u,d),(u,d,u),(u,u,u),(u,d,d)\} , \{(d,u,u),(d,u,d),(d,d,u),(d,d,d)\} \Big\}
$$

If you take any other set, it will depend on $X_1$. Try it!

##### A different way of understanding $\mathcal F(1)$

That is through the following lemma :

> $\mathcal F(1)$ is *precisely* the set of all events that can be obtained as preimages of $X_1: \Omega \to \mathbb R$.

So what we need to do, is characterize the preimages of $X_1$. Let $S \subset \mathbb R$. Then $\{\omega : X_1(\omega) \in S\} = \{\omega : \omega_1 \in S\}$. But then, this event doesn't depend upon $\omega_2$ and $\omega_3$.  Now see the magic :

$$
\emptyset =  \{\omega : X_1(\omega) \in \emptyset\}\\
\Omega =  \{\omega : X_1(\omega) \in \{u,d\}\} \\
\{(u,u,d),(u,d,u),(u,u,u),(u,d,d)\}  = \{\omega : X_1(\omega) \in \{u\}\} \\
\{(d,u,u),(d,u,d),(d,d,u),(d,d,d)\} = \{\omega : X_1(\omega) \in \{d\}\}
$$

now do you understand the beauty of the lemma? We obtain the sets we need as preimages of $X_1$ under certain well chosen sets.

##### Onto $\mathcal{F}(2)$

For $\mathcal F(2)$ we again use free choice for the last coordinate $X_3$. So if an event in $\mathcal F(2)$ contains $(u,d,*)$ it must contain all values of $*$ so that the third coordinate stops mattering for that event.

With that, we get four fundamental sets , corresponding to the first two combinations of $X_1,X_2$ as $(u,u,*),(u,d,*),(d,u,*)$ and $(d,d,*)$:
$$
F_1 = \{(u,u,d),(u,u,u)\} \\
F_2 = \{(u,d,d),(u,d,d)\} \\
F_3 = \{(d,u,d),(d,u,u)\} \\
F_4 = \{(d,d,d),(d,d,u)\}
$$

Any event in $\mathcal F(2)$ is a union of the events $F_1,F_2,F_3,F_4$. For example $F_1 \cup F_2 \in \mathcal F(2)$, $F_3 \cup F_4 \cup F(1) \in \mathcal F(2)$. So $\mathcal F(2)$ is precisely given by the set $$\mathcal F(2) = \{\cup_{i \in \mathcal I} F_i : \mathcal I \subset \{1,2,3,4\}\}$$

(Note : the empty union gives $\emptyset$ and $\Omega = F_1 \cup F_2 \cup F_3 \cup F_4$, so they very much belong to the filtration).

And how to get this using the preimage method? Some examples are given from which I'd assume you'd be able to get the general idea :
$$
F_1 = \{\omega : (X_1(\omega),X_2(\omega)) \in \{(u,u)\}\} \\
F_3 = \{\omega : (X_1(\omega),X_2(\omega)) \in \{(d,u)\}\} \\
F_2 \cup F_4 = \{\omega : (X_1(\omega),X_2(\omega)) \in \{(u,d), (d,d)\}\}
F_1 \cup F_2 \cup F_4 = \{\omega : (X_1(\omega),X_2(\omega)) \in \{(u,u), (u,d), (d,d)\}\}
$$

Try to see that $\mathcal F(1) \subset \mathcal F(2)$ (hint : try to write each element of $\mathcal F(1)$ as a union of the $F_i$).

Comment: What an answer. I am still reading it but I wanted to thank you first. Thank you very much:)

Comment: You're welcome! I'm going to sleep now, so I will reply only after a few hours. Do ask any question you want, of course!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer again. To get you right, the sample space contains the following elements $\Omega=\{ (u,u,d),(u,d,u),(u,u,u),(u,d,d), (d,u,u),(d,u,d),(d,d,u),(d,d,d) \}$.  So in other words it forms a partition. Since $\mathcal{F}(3)= P(\Omega)$ it follows: $| \mathcal{F}(3)| =2^{|\Omega|}=2^{2^3}$

Comment: @Alif That is correct. So, *every* event can be found using $X(1),X(2),X(3)$. This is basically because every element of the sample space , as a singleton event, can be found using these three values.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. Is it always the case that on finite probability spaces a parition coincides with $\Omega$.

Comment: @Alif I don't hundred percent get what you are saying, but yes in finite probability spaces you can partition the space element-by-element which makes things nice for usage, and the whole partition thing also helps when you are looking at filtrations, because generating events for a filtration also form a partition, like how $F_1,F_2,F_3,F_4$ partitioned $\Omega$ but also generated $\mathcal F(2)$.

Comment: @Alif Also, I forgot completely and just gave you a +1 for your question, for the interest you have showed and the effort you have put in before and after my answer. Thanks, role model to the site.

Comment: Thank you, but I would rather say you are the role model:)  For $\mathcal{F}(1)$ the parition would be the two sets besides $\Omega, \emptyset$

Comment: @Alif Exactly , that is correct. One small thing : even in infinite probability spaces, you will get partitions from filtrations if there's a sequence of random variables that takes finitely (or countably) many discrete values with non-zero probability. So you can get generalizations of what we've done above on infinite spaces, which is very interesting.

Comment: Perfect. Now everything seems right to me. It is a great feeling. Thank you for getting me there:)

Comment: @Alif We both got there. Looking forward to seeing you on the site more often. I will frequent your questions, although I may not answer them but I'll take a look for sure.

Comment: This is very kind of you. I am looking forward to  hearing from you again:)